# Python-Tkinter multiple entry widgets calculation error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

i want to create simple program for multiple items calculation and amount totals.
only first row item calculation is working, But i need to create 5 items with rows and entry widgets,
i was already create second row, but calculation error coming..

sorry for my bad english

the code is

```
from tkinter import *
def mul(event):
    a=float(t1.get())
    b=float(t2.get())
    c=a*b
    t3.insert(0,c)
    g=float(v1.get())
    h=float(v2.get())
    i=g*h
    v3.insert(0,c)

win=Tk()
win.geometry('850x450')

l1=Label(win,text="SL")
l1.grid(row=1,column=0)
l2=Label(win,text="price")
l2.grid(row=0,column=1)
l3=Label(win,text="Qty/Kgs")
l3.grid(row=0,column=2)
l4=Label(win,text="Amount")
l4.grid(row=0,column=3)
l5=Label(win,text="DR")
l5.grid(row=2,column=0)

t1=Entry(win)
t1.grid(row=1,column=1)
t2=Entry(win)
t2.grid(row=1,column=2)
t3=Entry(win)
t3.grid(row=1,column=3)

v1=Entry(win)
v1.grid(row=2,column=1)
v2=Entry(win)
v2.grid(row=2,column=2)
v3=Entry(win)
v3.grid(row=2,column=3)

t2.bind('<Return>',mul)
v2.bind('<Return>',mul)

win.mainloop()
```

The error is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\godde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "calc11.py", line 3, in mul
a=float(t1.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: @quamrana Indentation here seems pretty straight forward, so i updated it. Not sure if OP _indent_ this though

Comment: Now that @CoolCloud has sorted out the indentation, please update the question with the details of this `calculation error`.

Comment: Anyway the error i guess is `v3.insert(0,c)` should be `v3.insert(0,i)`.

Comment: Ok, so the error is that `t1` contains an empty string, which won't convert to a `float`. What do you *want* to happen in this case?

Comment: @quamrana I think my answer, would take care of it, right?

Comment: @CoolCloud: You may have discovered an additional error that the OP hasn't come across yet. I'm just concentrating on what the OP is actually telling me.

Comment: @quamrana I actually dint notice the fact that OP edited the Q with the error xp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here, might be a logical error. Try saying `v3.insert(0,i)` instead of `v3.insert(0,c)` . But still the GUI seems pretty lacking. If you want to improve the functionality, here ya go.

```
from tkinter import *

count = 0
def mul(event):
    global count
    count += 1
    if count > 1:
        t3.delete(0,END)
    a=float(t1.get())
    b=float(t2.get())
    c=a*b
    t3.insert(0,c)
def mul2(event):
    global count
    count += 1
    if count > 1:
        v3.delete(0,END)
    g=float(v1.get())
    h=float(v2.get())
    i=g*h
    v3.insert(0,i)

win=Tk()
win.geometry('850x450')

l1=Label(win,text="SL")
l1.grid(row=1,column=0)
l2=Label(win,text="price")
l2.grid(row=0,column=1)
l3=Label(win,text="Qty/Kgs")
l3.grid(row=0,column=2)
l4=Label(win,text="Amount")
l4.grid(row=0,column=3)
l5=Label(win,text="DR")
l5.grid(row=2,column=0)

t1=Entry(win)
t1.grid(row=1,column=1)
t2=Entry(win)
t2.grid(row=1,column=2)
t3=Entry(win)
t3.grid(row=1,column=3)

v1=Entry(win)
v1.grid(row=2,column=1)
v2=Entry(win)
v2.grid(row=2,column=2)
v3=Entry(win)
v3.grid(row=2,column=3)

t2.bind('<Return>',mul)
v2.bind('<Return>',mul2)

win.mainloop()
```

Ive used binding on two different entry widgets separately and hence more easy to reduce empty string error.

Hope it helped.

Cheers